# Navigation schema in Android app

Tags: android, tabs, navigation

I have 6 main views in my app (maybe more in the future), and 3 of them are siblings (that is, they are listViews with the same elements ordered or filtered in different ways). One of the 3 siblings screens has to be the first screen showed to the user when he logs in.

So I though that the best implementation for the navigation in my app could be 3 scrollable tabs with the 3 siblings screens, and place all the other options for navigation in a navigationDrawer (that is a map, profile, settings, about, ...). But here http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/app-structure.html#top-level-switching says that is not a good idea to mix both navigation patterns, and in fact once implemented the scrollable tabs are ABOVE the navigation drawer (pretty ugly).

So, what would be the correct navigation schema for my app? Maybe remove the scrollable tabs and put all the navigation related items in the navigationDrawer? Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion to you, is to watch the "Navigation anti patterns" video from the wonderful series "Android design in action".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sww4omntVjs&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc8j2B95zGMb8muZvrIy-wcF

And the slides can be found here:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/+NickButcher/albums/5981768132040708401

They actually talk about and demonstrate do's and dont's for Android app navigation. And this is from guys at Google that work with this every day. Very helpful!